# Programmatically set delegate to every UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios

i'm more or less new to objective C programming, so maybe this will sound a little weird..

i'm trying to programmatically set the delegate of a lot of UITextFields from an UIViewController that is the parent of the actual UIViewController that contains the UITextfields.
Basically it the same of doing right-click on the UITextField, and setting the UIViewController as the delegate of this control.

I've tried to loop the self.view.subview array but I only get 2 UIImageViews (i'm still trying to understand this... i think is something about using static cells but I'm confused). So the next option was to loop through all the properties of the class.

Using a mix of codes of stackoverflow i've almost done it, but I still need to send the message to the textfield per se.

```
unsigned int count = 0;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList( [self class], &count );
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    const char* propertyName = property_getName(property);
    NSLog( @"property: %s", propertyName ); //this is actually correctly writing the name of the properties
    objc_msgSend((id)GetTheObjectThroughTheName, @selector(setDelegate:), self);

}
```

The thing is I don't know how to get the object related to the property only using the name of the property... but if i can get it and use the objc_msgsend using that object as receiver it will be solved.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use an IBOutlet collection, or an NSArray of your textfields you could use a for-in loop to set the delegates.  (PS; why in the heck would you want to go straight to objc_msg_send to set a delegate?)

Comment: Could you clarify your reasons for needing to set all delegates at runtime (as opposed to beforehand), and what you mean by "parent" (a navigation controller?) and "right-click"?

Comment: the thing is I don't want the people who draw the forms to set the delegate of the UITextFields... so I prefer to set them in runtime from the parent.
I mean parent by the class that the UIViewControllers will inherit from ( FormViewController:FatherViewController)...
sorry if it's not the exact term (spanish guy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to maintain if you went through the view hierarchy instead.  Something like...

```
- (NSArray *)textFieldsInView:(UIView *)view {
    NSMutableArray * fields = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (UIView *sub in [view subviews]) {
        if ([sub isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [fields addObject:sub];
        } else if ([[sub subviews] count] > 0) {
            [fields addObjectsFromArray:[self textFieldsInView:sub]];
        }
    }
    return fields;
}
```

...should get you the list of fields you want.  (Call `[self textFieldsInView:self.view];` in viewDidLoad.)

Comment: This was my first approach... I totally agree that it's easier. 
But I think i'm forgetting something because this is returning weird things...

if i put "NSLog(@"%@",sub.debugDescription);" inside the for-in, I'm getting only two UIImageView...

maybe the problem is the self.view is not exactly the view I think... if I get the description of the self.view I get my viewcontroller class... but inside my viewController I have a Navigation Item and a table view with 2 different sections (static cells btw)

Comment: If you put `NSLog(@"%@", self.view);` inside viewDidLoad:, what does it say?

Comment: copypasted: <UITableView: 0x71b0400; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6886850>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>. Delegate: DyRegicorViewController, DataSource: DyRegicorViewController     DyRegicorViewController is the class of my vc

Comment: Are your UITextField objects inside the cells of a UITableView?  If so, then you probably need to configure them inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method whenever a new cell is created.

Comment: yes, they are inside the cells of the UITableview, but i thought that with your code it would loop through the cells. I'll try to change the cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: My code would fail in that case because the cells aren't actually created until the table needs them.

Comment: finally worked with your code :) but instead of looking for textfields in the self.view, what I do is to look for the textfields in the cell itself (in the cellForRowAtIndexPath).
You've been really helpful!!! thanks a lot!!